# Website; let user add location and get coordinates

Tags: mysql, web, maps, coordinates

I've been developing a website where users can add a place (say a store in a city) and it is stored in a database. Now I would like to be able to display these places on a interactive map on my website. I got a bing maps developer key but it seems i can only display the data if i have the coordinates (lon/lat). Is that true? And if so, how do I get the coordinates automatically once a user adds new data?

As an example: You add Store XYZ in City XYZ, but you DON'T have to enter the coordinates. Now, this info is stored, but I don't have the coordinates..

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: This can be done using [Google Maps API V3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) I don't know if Bing is suitable

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any plans on allowing your users to insert place locations in a map or by filling some lat/long data, I suggest you to use google web services to get geolocation of those places. You'll need to format the input you send into something like an address to get it working properly though.

[See this Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

Comment: Thanks, sounds like that is what I need. Will check it out this weekend!